# I have to take a particular row from an entity,based on a condition where the particular value is the greatest among all?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have:

```
@Query("select  distinct t from AssessmentTemplate t where t.riskLabel.name=:name group by t.id having max(t.version)") 
List<AssessmentTemplate> getVersion(@RequestParam String name);
```

I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected AST node: max near line 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Change after `having`:
After the keyword `having` you need to mention the condition.
I believe it to be `t.version = max(t.version)` according to what I understood from your question.